# Automatically get access_token in MVC client (IdentityServer)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, identityserver4, access-token, refresh-token

I code “MVC Client” just as in “Creating an MVC client” https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_interactive_aspnetcore.html#creating-an-mvc-client
My main goal is when access_token is expired to get new one with refresh_token.
I need it not for API access but for “MVC Client” authentication/authorization.

So, I thought before “MVC Client” issues redirect to IdentityServer to its login page (http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=bla, bla, bla) just intercept it and send instead of it just get new access_token (with refresh_token) w/o user need to enter his credentials.

So, I just need to get any event before “MVC Client” decides that access_token no longer valid and tries to redirect to IdentityServer login.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";

        })                
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options => {
                options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
                options.Cookie.MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
                options.SlidingExpiration = false;

                //options.Cookie.s ExpireTimeSpan   = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);


                options.Events = new Func<CookieAuthenticationEvents>(() =>
                {
                    var cookieAuthenticationEvents = new CookieAuthenticationEvents( );

                    var f = cookieAuthenticationEvents.OnRedirectToLogin;
                    var f1 = cookieAuthenticationEvents.OnValidatePrincipal;
                    var f2 = cookieAuthenticationEvents.OnSignedIn;

                    cookieAuthenticationEvents.OnRedirectToLogin = ( context ) =>
                    {
                        return f(context);
                    };
                    cookieAuthenticationEvents.OnValidatePrincipal = ( context ) =>
                    {
                        return f1(context);
                    };
                    cookieAuthenticationEvents.OnSignedIn = ( context ) =>
                    {
                        return f2(context);
                    };

                    return cookieAuthenticationEvents;
                }
                )( );
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code";       
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");


      //          options.Events = new Func<>


            options.Events = new Func<OpenIdConnectEvents>(() =>
            {
                var openIdConnectEvents = new OpenIdConnectEvents( );
                var f = openIdConnectEvents.OnAuthenticationFailed;
                var f1 = openIdConnectEvents.OnAccessDenied;
                var f2 = openIdConnectEvents.OnTokenValidated;
                var f3 = openIdConnectEvents.OnAccessDenied;
                openIdConnectEvents.OnAuthenticationFailed = ( context ) =>
                {
                    return f(context);
                };
                openIdConnectEvents.OnAccessDenied = ( context ) =>
                {
                    return f1(context);
                };
                openIdConnectEvents.OnTokenValidated = ( context ) =>
                {
                    return f2(context);
                };
                openIdConnectEvents.OnAccessDenied = ( context ) =>
                {
                    return f3(context);
                };

                return openIdConnectEvents;
            }
                )( );

            });
    }
```

On every line with *"return f3(context);"* I put break point with anticipation to hit it before getting to Login page of IdentityServer – no luck .

This is client config.

```
                new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequireConsent = false,
                RequirePkce = true,

                // where to redirect to after login
                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },

                // where to redirect to after logout
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "api1"
                },

                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                AccessTokenLifetime = 150,
                AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 150,
                UserSsoLifetime = 150
            }
```

How to do it - refresh token automatically w/o user interaction for MVC Client authentication (not for API access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Here it is: 
https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples/tree/aspnetcore21/AutomaticTokenManagement

The key point here is to override this method

```
public override async Task ValidatePrincipal ( CookieValidatePrincipalContext context )
```

from class

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationEvents
```